# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in Combine while .store(in: &subscrptions)

Tags: swift, combine

```
 // MARK: - Combine
    /// First Image
    let firstImage = UnsplashAPI.randomeImage()
      .flatMap { RandomImageResponse in
        ImageDownloader.download(url: RandomImageResponse.urls.regular)
      }
    /// Second Image
    let secondImage = UnsplashAPI.randomeImage()
      .flatMap { RandomImageResponse in
        ImageDownloader.download(url: RandomImageResponse.urls.regular)
      }
    
    firstImage.zip(secondImage)
    
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .sink(receiveCompletion: { [unowned self ] completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            break
        case .failure():
          self.gameState = .stop
        }
      },
      receiveValue: { [unowned self] first, second in
        self.gameImages = [first, second, second, second].shuffled()
        self.gameScoreLabel.text = "Score: \(self.gameScore)"

            // TODO: Handling game score
            self.stopLoaders()
            self.setImages()
      })
      .store(in: &subscrptions)
```

That's my code:
while using `.store(in: &subscrptions)`

Here is also --> `var subscrptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []`

This is only happening with Xcode 14. Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is probably complaining about the block that begins:

`receiveValue: { [unowned self] first, second in`

It can't infer the types of `first` and `second`.  You might be able to resolve the error by indicating their types explicitly.  I don't know what type `ImageDownloader.download` returns,  But here's an example using simple types:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5].publisher
let strings = ["a", "b", "c", "d"].publisher

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

numbers.zip(strings)
    .sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let err):
            debugPrint(err)
        case .finished:
            print("Finshed")
        }
    } receiveValue: { (first:Int, second:String) in
        print(first, second)
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Note how the types are made explicit in the block using `(first:Int, second:String) in`